# Is there any app to track my vegetarian days?

Tags: android, statistics

I am turning vegan but occasionally out of necessity I have to eat meat.

Is there any app which will let me log days when I eat meat and keep track of all my vegan days? I want to see how many days I was vegan over for example, a month or year. The count would motivate me to hold back on the days I had to eat meat.

This would be similar to a quit smoking app.

All apps out there I searched were either for restraunts or tracking diet.

I am using a Samsung phone with Android OS on it.

Comment: @Nic thanks for your comment...but habbit building is a bit different...i want more like habbit quitting....it appears same but it works differently with app and it helps with app...to build motivation...

Comment: Could something like [Loop Habit Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.isoron.uhabits) fit this? Also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.isoron.uhabits/) for the additional habit of prefering FOSS (free and open source) apps over proprietary ones with trackers :)

Comment: @Izzy deleted my answer, but we're not going to argue :-) However, I stand by what I said - an acceptable answer to "Is there any app which will let me log days when i eat meat and keep track of all my vegan days?" ***is*** your calendar app, which is bundled with your 'phone. If you want more than marking the calendar with which days you are vegan & which days you are not, then you have to tell us what you want. Please help us to help you and detail your requirements; the more info that you give us, the better that we can help you. Please read [ask]. Welcome aboard;I hope that we can help you

Comment: for some reason I am not able to comment. May be because this question was ported from the vegan stack. Can you put the loop habit tracker as an answer. I will accept it. For the comments asking me details...i wanted an app that is similar to quit smoking app....not a calender app as its better to use the diet tracker over calender... Thanks.

Comment: @Mawg and how do you the statistics in the calendar app (quote: "how many days I was vegan...over a month...over a year")?

Comment: You mark each day and count them. That's a total. No statistics were requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means tracking a habit – so **[Loop Habit Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.isoron.uhabits)** should fit this. It is also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.isoron.uhabits/) for the additional habit of prefering FOSS (free and open source) apps over proprietary ones with trackers

The app offers you detailed statistics, including widgets to see them right on your homwscreen.

[image: statistics] [image: widgets]
<sup>*Loop Habit Tracker:* statistics, widgets (source: [Gootle Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.isoron.uhabits); click images to enlarge)</sup>

I haven't tried the app myself, so I cannot tell how well it works. But as you already confirmed it fits, it fits

Comment: There's also beeminder if you need some extra motivation...

Comment: @henning could you make that an answer with some more details?